# Como descobrir o IP interno?

Tags: javascript, ip, webrtc

Estou procurando uma solução para saber o `ip` interno de uma maquina.

A ideia é que através de um site, quando o utilizador acessa-lo, saber qual o `ip` interno dele, e depois procurar todos outros `ip's`, e achar qual é a maquina que tem uma aplicação instalada.

Até agora conseguir fazer isso com o RTCPeerConnection mas não funciona em todos os browsers.

Comment: Acho que perdi alguma coisa. RTCPeerConnection é uma solução para navegadores, não é? Mas você diz que a aplicação tem que ser instalada? Que tipo de tecnologia/instalação você realmente tem? Porque se fosse uma instalação de um programa desktop, seria muito fácil pegar o IP verdadeiro da máquina.

Comment: ola acho que expliquei mal, no cliente vai ter uma maquina com um servidor, que vai fazer a autenticação com o site. a ideia é fazer algo tipo o chromecast, assim que ligo em um site que esta pronto para o chromecast ele mostra um icon

Comment: Não posso te auxiliar em sua solução javascript, mas apenas contextualizando: não existe ou eu não entendo o que poderia ser "IP interno". Geralmente um computador pode ter nenhuma ou várias interfaces de rede com um IP configurado em cada uma. Por exemplo: você pode ter três interfaces: wlan, ethernet e loopback. Assim você pode ter três endereços de IP reconhecíveis e utilizáveis (contudo para rotas/finalidades diferentes).

O que você quer dizer com "IP Interno"?

Comment: ex: o chormecast, consegue saber qual é o seu IP(ip interno: 192.168.2.110 ; seu ip externo: 88.888.8.88), ok? se eu tenho o chromecast instalado na minha rede, quando entro em um site que esta compativel com ele, automaticamente aparece um icon que eu posso ver o conteudo do site no meu chromecast. a minha ideia é fazer algo parecido. um ex: é este site (http://net.ipcalf.com/) ele mostra o seu ip interno, o ip da sua maquina

Comment: Entendi. Bom, acho que não faz sentido você falar em "IP interno" e "IP externo" porque em muitos casos eles serão o mesmo. Conceitualmente IP é IP. Quanto ao javascript, como eu disse, eu não posso ajudar. Mas eu particularmente duvido que a descoberta do Chromecast na rede seja feita por um javascript no browser que escaneia as interfaces de rede toda vez que você entra em um site habilitado para isso.

Comment: Ok Francisco obrigado vou pesquisar mais sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 3):

Uma resposta para isto foi postada no StackOverflow em ingles pelo usuário [nodyou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1088990/nodyou): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653065/get-local-ip-address-in-node-js

```
var os=require('os');
var ifaces=os.networkInterfaces();
for (var dev in ifaces) {
  var alias=0;
  ifaces[dev].forEach(function(details){
    if (details.family=='IPv4') {
      console.log(dev+(alias?':'+alias:''),details.address);
      ++alias;
    }
  });
}
```

Se for necessário mais detalhes, a documentação está em http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces

Comment: woliveirajr, obrigado, vou ver isso.

Answer (score 0):

Michel Melo dis que o seu cliente vai ter "uma maquina com um servidor". Neste caso, significa que, por exemplo, tem um WAMP o um MAMP na maquina.
Usando este servidor, localemente, o cliente vai colocar dados, usando um software cliente (por exemple Firefox)
Exemple:
Site principal com Linux é um servidor Web
Site local com WAMP
Client usando Firefox no WAMP

O problema de Michel nao parace estar "Como meu servidor Linux vai saber o endereço IP do Firefox do usario", porque o seu usario nao vai conectar-se no Linux.
O problema de Michel esta "Como meu servidor Linux pode saber o IP do servidor WAMP que vai se conectar".
E isso?

Se e isso, a resposta nao pode ser "Usa JS" porque WAMP nao vai usar JS.

O outro problem e que, se a ligaçao internet do client e pertubada, o seu rede local pode receber uma outra endereço IP. E neste caso, o "servidor" do client nao vai ser mas reconhecido pelo servidor "global".

Analisando isso, eu acho que a melhor opçao e transmitir no servido local um codigo de conexao. E cada vez este servidor local vai se conectar no servido "global", ele vai transmitir o codigo. A IP nao me parece um opçao fiavel o suficiante.

Comment: Aqui é diferente de um fórum, as perguntas e respostas devem brilhar por si própria, por isto não fazemos saudações nas postagens. Você não fala português nativamente?

Answer (score 0):

```
var object_ip = function(){
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ){
        let Ips = {};
        let counter = 1;
        let os=require('os');
        let ifaces=os.networkInterfaces();
        for( let i = 0; i < Object.keys(ifaces).length; i++){
            ifaces[Object.keys(ifaces)[i]].forEach(el=>{
                if(!!el.address){
                    Ips['Ipv'+counter.toString()] = el.address;
                    counter++;
                }
            })
        }

        if(!!Object.keys(Ips).length){
            resolve(Ips);
        }else{
            reject("Dont Have IP");
        }
    })
}

object_ip()

    .then( function(result){ 
        console.log(result); 
    })
    .catch( function(error){ 
        console.error(error);
    })
```

Comment: Salvo engano, esse código é somente para Node JS, certo? Como aplicaria em um site como foi solicitado na pergunta?